# Settings shortcut widget in Galaxy Tab running Android 5.0.2?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, app-widgets, samsung-galaxy-tab-4, nova-launcher

I'm using Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 with Nova launcher. On widgets section, I don't  have settings shortcut. Below is the screenshot. What I want is notifications log from that shortcut.

[image: Settings quick search]

Comment: Are you open to 3rd-party alternative? Perhaps [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antziola.settingsshortcuts) can help?

Comment: Nope. I want to keep using nova.

Comment: Abhishek, Andrew T. didn't suggest an alternative launcher. You can keep using both the Nova launcher and that app at the same time.

Comment: Yeah that worked.